# URL taking more time to load in iframe how to escape url using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

How to load another URL from text file if first URL is taking more time to load in iframe?

I am loading 1st URL from text file in iframe and checking load time. But if i have dum URL which means that is not present, in that case my code is stuck. So i want to bypass to another URL after some time limitation, it has to continue the application.

Comment: You can use the `load` event of an `<iframe>` to detect that it has done loading anything (including an error page, I believe. I mean, you cannot know it is an error page, you can just know it finished loading anything). Combining this with `setTimeout(function () { iframe.src = anotherURL; }, 5000);` and having the `load` event (or another action that should happen) cancel the timer could be the solution.

Comment: But i just want when u url is not found or not open then it has to go next url. For that i want to give a time limit, when a url is not open in within 2 minute then it has to pickup next url from text file.How i do this?

Comment: Is this a same origin URL? If so, you can use the `load` event and then try accessing the document using `iframe.contentWindow.document` (for example). If you fail, it means the URL has failed loading. But, if it is a cross origin URL, the iFrame is a black box to you and you cannot know whether it failed or not.

Comment: suppose my 1st url is http://www.gmail.com that is loaded but 2nd is like that http://www.anything_like.com, that is not a correct url. There my iframe is unable to load.So, how can i pass the next url to continue.

Comment: Sounds like the iFrame is supposed to show cross origin URLs. You cannot know whether it failed.

Comment: But can i check with iframe.onload function in which if  i will apply variable flag which is true when url loaded and false when it will not load. On the basis of that it will go to next url, but how to do this i confused. Is there a method which can check a url is loaded or not?

Comment: No, there is no way using client side only. Your server can check whatever you want (if you control it). `load` fires even when the browser determines that the URL could not be loaded.